# Is the following statement about sequences true or false?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

Is the following statement true or false ?

The  sequences $\{f_n\}$ in $C^{[0, 1]}$ must contain a uniformly
convergent subsequence When $\lvert\,f_n(t)\rvert \leq 3,\, \forall t \in [0, 1]$ and $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

My attempts :   I was thinking about the Arzela Ascoli theorem... a sequence $\{f_n\}, n\in\mathbb{N}$ of continuous functions on an interval $I = [a, b]$ is uniformly bounded if there is a number $M$ such that 
                    $f_n(x) \leq M$

for every function  $f_n$  belonging to the sequence, and every $x \in [a, b].$

SO THE GIVEN STATEMENT IS TRUE...

Is my answer is correct or incorrect...I would be thankful for verified my mistake ..

Comment: You should really choose a better title.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: what title i have to give @ mixedmaths

Comment: The closure of a non-empty open ball in an infinite-dimensional normed linear space is never compact.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Consider the case of $f_n(x) = x^n$.
Note that $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise where
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } 0 \leq x < 1 \\ 1 & \text{if } x = 1. \end{cases}$$
Suppose we can find a subsequence of $(f_n)_n$  which converges uniformly.
Then, it must also converge pointwise to $f$ (why?). Therefore...

Comment: ok,,,that mean i got  two subsequences f(x) = 0 is uniformly convergent but f(x) = 1 is not not uniformly convergent,,,,,,,,Am i correct ? @ parsiad

Comment: @lomberlego: I am not sure what you are trying to say, so I will assume that it is incorrect. When you write $f(x)$, that is a point. When you write $f$, that is a function. You should be thinking of sequences of functions. What do we know about the limit of a uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions?

Answer (score 0):

What you have written so far is not sufficient for an answer in my opinion.

Note that uniformly bounded is different from uniform convergence,
and the Arzela Ascoli theorem requires another condition for the sequence in question.
Is that other condition satisfied? If no, try to look for a counterexample, if yes, you can apply the theorem.

Comment: i  got one  counter exmple  (-1)^n,,,,which is uniformly bounded,,@supinf,,,is my counter example is correct or not ?

Comment: if you mean the constant functions, that is not a correct counterexample (they are equicontinuous)

Comment: i take  fn(x) = sin^n(x)  in [0,π/2].........Is it correct @ supinf